# Воспроизведение потокового видео в Android

Tags: android, видео

Всем привет. Есть  задача, сделать вещание видео на мобильные девайсы. Вопрос, каким образом нужно вещать в интернет видеотрансляцию, чтобы можно было его воспроизвести в Android девайсах, и с помощью каких средств можно в андроид воспроизвести потоковое видео.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычный `VideoView` отлично воспроизводит видеопотоки, если они закодированы в [поддерживаемый формат](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)  
Как организовать стриминг, можно найти [вот так](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=stream%20video%20server&es_th=1)

Comment: Доволен ответом.

Comment: @awarskiy, на здоровье!

Answer (score 2):

Что касается воспроизведения потока на Android:

1. [Vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle), закрытый код, прост в использовании, дублирует классы и методы из sdk.
2. libvlc, самому компилить или брать [готовые либы](https://github.com/maruku/libvlc), [пример](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample), открытый код.
3. [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org), сложно